# How to create an App user in a Box account?

Tags: box-api

I'm super new to developer BOX and I would like to create an app only user in my BOX account. I found out this [link](https://box-content.readme.io/docs/app-users) which guides me through the process. BUT, I'm not able to find out ho to proceed with the following things:

```
1) How to request an enterprise access token using the JWT
2) How to use the enterprise access token to make a request for a new app user.
```

I'm super sorry if this question is stupid or trivial. I'm super new to this area and I really hope I get some help as I would love to work more in this field.

Answer (score 0):

[This page on the Box documentation site](https://box-content.readme.io/docs/app-auth) walks through how to create an Enterprise access token.

As you mentioned once you generate the Enterprise access token, you can then create a new App User using the Users endpoint. Here's an example in cURL for this.

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users \
-H "Authorization: Bearer REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_ENTERPRISE_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-d '{"name": "Example Name", "is_platform_access_only": true}' \
-X POST
```

Comment: After requesting the following command in my command line I receive the following error. curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  -H
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  -d
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: name
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  "is_platform_access_only"
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  -X